# Заполнение массива данными php

Tags: php, html

Есть форма ввода. Надо заполнить массив данными из формы и вывести. Но у меня не получается аккумулировать записи. Каждый ввод стирает предыдущий. Как сделать так чтобы записи добавлялись к массиву?

```html
<form action="/notes.php" method="post">
 <label for="text">Новая запись:</label>
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text"><br>
 <button type="submit">Добавить новую запись</button>
 </form>
<?php
$arr = [];
$newNote = $_POST['text'];
$arr[] = $newNote;
foreach ($arr as $value){
 echo $value;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать так чтобы записи добавлялись к массиву?

Использовать сессию для ввода/вывода *notes.php*, до завершения надо сохранить в один из вариантов представленных ниже:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Добавит запись потом можно будет вывести
$_SESSION['notes'][] = filter_var ($_POST['text'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

---

Использовать файлы для ввода/вывода записей (не самый удачный)

```
$note = filter_var ($_POST['text'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$yor_file = file_put_contents('notes.txt', $note.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

---

Использовать базу данных для ввода/вывода записей (рекомендованный)

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO notes (text) VALUES (:text)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $_POST['text']);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

Будет логичнее потом расспечатывать, на той странице которая послала эти записи.

Скорее в связке с сессией, которая до завершения сохранит все в базу данных, будет оптимальным решением.

---

- [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php) - Ассоциативный массив, содержащий переменные сессии, которые доступны для текущего скрипта.
- [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)  - Если notes.txt не существует, файл будет создан. Добавит в файл новую запись FILE_APPEND.
- [Класс PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php) - Представляет соединение между PHP и сервером базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

Сомнительная у Вас идея, но пусть так:

```
<form action="/notes.php" method="post">
    <label for="text">Новая запись:</label>
    <input type="text[]" name="text[]" id="text"><br>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['text']))
foreach ($_POST['text'] as $value){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="text[]" value="'.$value.'">';
}
?>
    <button type="submit">Добавить новую запись</button>
    </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['text']))
foreach ($_POST['text'] as $value){
    echo $value.'<BR>';
}
?>
```

Comment: У меня выдает ошибку " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "